# I want to add to my button a cooldown but I have no clue how

Tags: html, css, reactjs

It's a React.Js Website. If you know how I can add a cooldown to that button it would help me a lot since it would make the Contact Me page better. I didn't include all the code
for more information add my Discord: uvejs#5162

```
import "./contactpage.css"
import Footer from "../../Components/Footer/Footer";
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

const initialInputs = {
    return (
        <div className="group">
            <Navbar />
            <form action="" ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} className="contact-form">
                <label className="form-input-label" > Your Name
                    <input required name="from_name" value={inputs.from_name} onChange={handleChange} className="form-input" type="text"  />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label required className="form-input-label"> Your Email
                    <input name="from_email" value={inputs.from_email} onChange={handleChange} className="form-input" type="text"  />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label required className="form-input-label" > About Your Project
                    <input name="message" value={inputs.message} onChange={handleChange} className="form-input" type="text"  />
                </label>
                <button className="custom-button" > Send </button>
            </form>

            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code pen link - [cooldown button](https://codepen.io/paularce/pen/oLqqOe)

```js
$('button.cooldown').click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.prop('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function(){
    btn.prop('disabled', false);
  },15000);
});
```

```css
$buttonBaseColor: #336699;
$disableDuration: 15s;
button.cooldown{
  background: $buttonBaseColor;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 144px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:active, &:focus{
    outline: none;
  }
  &:disabled{
    background: darken($buttonBaseColor, 10%);
    color: darken(#fff, 15%);
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    &:after{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      height: 5px;
      background: darken($buttonBaseColor, 20%);
      animation: cooldown $disableDuration linear;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes cooldown {
   0% { width: 100%; }
   100% { width: 0; }
}





/* layout stuff */
section{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #333;
}
p{font-size: 12px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <button class="cooldown">Push Me!</button>
  <p>This button has a cool down of 30s until re-enabled</p>
</section>
```

Comment: That code snipped didn't help,  I tried it before.